# No data is deployed on the contract address

Tags: go-ethereum

I'm building a simple contract with inheritance as part of a tutorial and I'm getting an error “No data is deployed on the contract address” on the newBrand contract.

The contract is executing, but isn't deploying any data.

The code complies correctly, with no warnings before I deploy. **I've seen the other questions on the forum, for cases with the same error, but I cannot see why this simple contract will not deploy normally.** The solution to this issue has not been provided, just extra nuggets of information that do not explicitly explain 1) the mistake being make, and 2) the solution to the mistake.

The mortal contract deploys with no problems. Code below:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.6;

contract mortal{

  address public owner;

  function mortal(){
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  modifier onlyOwner{
    if (msg.sender == owner){
        _;
    }else{
        throw;
    }

  }

  function kill() onlyOwner{
    suicide(owner);
  }

}

contract newBrand is mortal{

  string public brandName;

  function newBrand(string _brandName){
    brandName = _brandName;
  }

  function changeBrandName(string _newBrandName) onlyOwner {
    brandName = _newBrandName;
  }

}
```

Simple stuff for most people on here I'm sure - any explanation would be greatly appreciated...